# How to reduce tensorflow-lite binary size with right configuration?

Tags: compiler-optimization, tensorflow-lite

I build the libtensorflowLite.so for android and it works well.But the binary size is 3.8M and it is too big as it is just reported with hundreds of KB. So, do i have improper build configuration? 
I add the android ndk and sdk path in tensorflow congfire.

I add following in tensorflow/lite/BUILD:

```
    cc_binary(
    name = "libtensorflowLite.so",
    linkopts = ["-shared", "-Wl,-soname=libtensorflowLite.so"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    linkshared = 1,
    copts = tflite_copts(),
    deps = [
        ":framework",
        "//tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels:builtin_ops",
    ],
    )
```

The build commit:

```
 bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/lite:libtensorflowLite.so 
 --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool 
 --cpu=arm64-v8a
 --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain
 --cxxopt="-std=c++11" 
 --verbose_failures
```

Comment: If you believe your build configuration is incorrect, please edit your question with details about your current build configuration.

Comment: @AndrewFan I update the configuration，do you have some idea?